Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'STRING')
Thanks in advance.
sorry if it is a silly mistake and i am new to sequlize
but i have 2 models in two different files
1st User
module.exports=(sequelize,DataTypes)=>{
    const User=sequelize.define("User",{
        email:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey:true,
            allowNull:false,
            validate:{
                notEmpty:true
            },
        },
        password:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:false,
            validate:{
                notEmpty:true
            },
        }
},
{
    freezeTableName: true
}
)
return User;
};

2nd Section
module.exports=(sequelize,DataTypes)=>{
    const Section=sequelize.define("Section",{
        HeroSec:{
            type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: true,
            allowNull:false,
            validate:{
                notEmpty:true
            },
        }
    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true
    });
    return Section;
}

i am trying to create a relationship between the two tables user and section with email as primary key as well as foreign key of the other
which is giving me errors after error
relationship code:
const Section = require("./Section");
const User = require("./User");

module.exports=(sequelize)=>{
    const user=User(sequelize)
    const section=Section(sequelize)
    user.hasOne(section);

    sequelize.sync({alter:true}).then(()=>{
    //
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
};

plz help me to connect these two using email as key
sorry if it is a naive error
thanks :)

What is the relation between your title and your posted code? Please describe the problem you are having (as [edit] to your post)

when i am running the code with all the three files it is showing me this error

You aren't calling toLowerCase() in your code, so it must be in a dependency of yours; we can't help you until and unless you find the exception's stack-trace and post it here. Learn how to use your debugger.

@HansKeﬆing,@dai i have updated my code littlebit can you plz check again

It seems you forgot to pass the second argument to model creation functions: DataTypes
